# Jmeter tex returned with underline

Tags: java, jmeter, underline, beanshell

In Jmeter Bean shell assertion, I'm storing a returned value to a string. The string is returned with an underline. It is displayed with underline. Though I'm not able to show underline in my below text.

https://myhost.com:1234/abc/def/ghi

I have to parse the above string to use it in http reuquerst. For that I'm using URI/URL class to get hostname , port and path etc; But all these works only after I get rid of underline from the text. How do I get rid of underline.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove underscores within the same Beanshell assertion using [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method like:

```
String myString = "your_string_with_underscores";
myString = myString.replaceAll("_","");
// do what you need with the "sanitized" string
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more Beanshell tips and tricks.